# How do I Simulate a LPT Printer to a legacy 16b MS-DOS PC from a Host PC

Tags: printer, lpt

I have to simulate a LPT Printer for a legacy PC on 16b running MS DOS, from another host pc running windows, in order to capture the print job and further process it.
There is no access to the legacy PC. Only physical access to the LPT port.

The connection between them is done with a LPT2USB tool. http://www.lpt2usb.net/

As I googled, printfil seems to be nearest as a solution. But I did not managed to simulate LPT printer with it.

I would like some ideas how to achieve this. (Commercial solutions or not).

Thank you for your time,

Comment: Sounds like you need to capture output of a legacy hardware system, one option is something from: http://www.photologic.ca/cap.html

Comment: These look like overkill. We have to edit the print and then print at a printer connected to the host. This process will be automatic.

Comment: Is it hardware or software that forces you to use a legacy system? If software, I would use a VM, where you can redirect DOS LPT output to a file.

Comment: Hardware. Its a production unit using this pc.

Comment: Reading data from a parallel port is hard enough without adding a USB converter into the mix, as they are designed for output, not input. On the other hand, I believe the parallel post uses open collector outputs, so you cannot feed data from one PC LPT port to another.

Comment: @hdhondt: Thank you for your comment. Unfortunately for me is not very clear your ideea.

Comment: @Vladds I suppose I'm saying there is no simple way to do this. I know of no hardware to do it and any software would have to be installed on the old PC. Using a USB-parallel adapter won't work either as they're not designed to take in input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can capture the output of the legacy PC Parallel LPT port with hardware.
Use a LPT cable to a capture PC, or parallel data recorder box hardware.
Such cables/hardware is made by Photologic Ltd.

Example:
Photologic Ltd. Model CS-ZN and Cables-To-Go Part#26886 lets you capture
 everything elegantly to a PC folder using Tera Term terminal emulator. 
  It will save everything on the cable including graphics and protocol
 escape sequences.  The transfer is quick as there is no mechanical
printer burden.

There is a youtube video at:  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kFOqP_CU5sI

Comment: The credits actually go @Brian.

Answer (score 0):

One way you should be able to achieve what you want is with a [Parallel-to-Serial Converter](http://www.blackbox.com/Store/Detail.aspx/Parallel-to-Serial-Converter-IV-for-HP-JetDirect-Parallel-Print-Servers/PI126A). Attach the device to the parallel port of the old PC, instead of a printer. Then connect the other end to the serial port (remember those?) of another PC. If necessary, install a [Serial Port PCI card](http://www.blackbox.com/Store/Detail.aspx/PC-Plus-Adapter-Card-Dual-Serial-PCI/IC128C%C4%82R3). Then all you need is some software like a [Terminal Emulator](http://en.softonic.com/s/serial-port-terminal-emulator) to read from the serial port.